# Android Design Library AppBar Scrolling behavior

Tags: android, appbar, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I have an own implementation of the scrolling toolbar in my app. In the new design library from Google
  http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html there is a new implementation for scrolling the toolbar. Thats very nice and easy to implement but my problem is there is some limitation. I have a Toolbar and behind there is an image and a tabstrip at the bottom. If i use the new implementation i cant get the toolbar with the image scroll off and the tabstrip dont disappear. I can get the tabstrip under the toolbar with the image but thats not my goal.

In the left thats the way it works correctly but the tabstrip isnt on top of the image. On the right it is correct but the tabstrip disappear if it scrolls
[image]

I hope it is clear what i mean and someone can help me, thank you.

I forget the xml declarations.
Left screenshot:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wvTest"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/abTest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivMainImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vActionBarBackgroundHolder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#37913C"
            android:alpha="0" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tbTest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:layout_height="65dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#37913C"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Right Screenshot:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wvTest"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/abTest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivMainImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vActionBarBackgroundHolder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#37913C"
            android:alpha="0" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tbTest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:layout_height="65dp" />

        <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="#8837913C"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Can you describe the exact behavior you're looking for? Do you want the `ImageView` to scroll away leaving only the `Toolbar` and the `PagerSlidingTabStrip`?

Comment: Hey, you can have a look at code in my question if that helps. If you can help with my query that would be awesome. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803313/pass-scroll-event-to-another-view