# How to pass scroll events to another view, but keep the tap/click events and react to them

Tags: android

I have a `HorizontalScrollView` whose drag/scroll events I want to pass to another view (or a gesture listener) but I want it to be able to react on click/tap events on its children. How do I do that?

I look at this: [Pass scroll event to another view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803313/pass-scroll-event-to-another-view)

but I need exactly the code that they left open-ended in the `onScroll` method - how do I pass the scroll to another view there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `HorizontalScrollView` do this:

```
private float xCoordinateOfScreenTouch;
private float xCoordinateOfDragRelease;
private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 40;

horizontalScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    xCoordinateOfScreenTouch = event.getX();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    xCoordinateOfDragRelease = event.getX();
                    float deltaX = xCoordinateOfDragRelease - xCoordinateOfScreenTouch;

                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {

                        if (xCoordinateOfDragRelease > xCoordinateOfScreenTouch) {
                            // left to right
                            // do whatever (pass the event)
                        } else {
                            // right to left
                            // do whatever (pass the event)
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

For it's children, whom the `ACTION_DOWN` event gets passed to by default, do this:

```
    textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                xCoordinateOfScreenTouch = event.getRawX();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following solution:

1/ find a common parent view of the ViewPager and the view that you are passing the events to.

2/ Create a customView that extends that parent view.

3/ Override dispatchTouchEvent using this;

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    if (mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)){
        // This is a scroll event -> Pass to the targetView;
        return findViewById(R.id.targetView).dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    // this is not a scroll event. dispatch normally
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

P/S: if do viewpager.setOnTouchListener(). The listener will only get called if the pages of viewPager (normally fragments) do not interested in the touch events.
For instance, your ViewPager contains a Fragment that has a ListView(recyclerView), then you OnTouchListener wont get called for Vertical scroll events but your ListView does. So you may miss the events depending on your page's view.

Comment: it is a `HorizontalScrollView`, not a ViewPager - does that change anything? I will try your suggestion today and let you know what happened

Comment: Yes, It does not affect anything. Yes, waiting for the result :D